# Need to change states within a Ionic Modal

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

So I do not know exactly on how to word this so I tried my best in the title.

What I am trying to do is have a modal popup and as the user clicks a next button, it slides to the next screen. Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish.

This is the home screen. When a user hits start a Ionic Modal pops up

[image: This is the home screen. When a user hits start a Ionic Modal pops up]

[image: This is the ionic modal. I am going to add a next button that allows a user to go to the next screen or go back to the previous screen before submitting.]

This is the ionic modal. I am going to add a next button that allows a user to go to the next screen or go back to the previous screen before submitting.

SO, I do not want to use states because I do not want to have to create a state in app.js for each and every screen. Is there a way to add multiple views and switch between them using a Ionic Modal? Or will I have to use States or create multiple Modals?

TL;DR -> I want to slide between views when a next or back button is pressed. (Survey application)

*NOT looking for code writing exactly, just trying to pick someones brain on how they would accomplish the sliding between views using a Modal*

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need on click on your button :

- force close of your modal
- use $state.location to change $state

This is what I'd try if I was in your situation ;)